# NameError with tensor flow: Why isn't this working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding

I'm trying to get this code running for hours but I could fix the problem. 
Does anyone know how I could fix ist? It throws a NameError: name 'embedding_weights' is not defined, but I have already defined it.

Thanks a lot!

```
def get_glove(path_to_glove, word2index_map):

    embedding_weights = {}
    count_all_words = 0
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_glove) as z:
        with open("glove.6B.300d.zip") as f:
            for line in f:
                vals = line.split()
                word = str(vals[0].decode("utf-8"))
                if word in word2index_map:
                    print(word)
                    count_all_words+=1
                    coefs = np_asarray(vals[:1],dtype='float32')
                    coefs/=np.linalg.norm(coefs)
                    embedding_weights[word] = coefs
                if count_all_words==vocabulary_size-1:
                    break
    return embedding_weights
word2embedding_dict = get_glove(path_to_glove,word2index_map)
```

Comment: In your original post the return was not inside the function (missing spaces). Was that a formatting problem of your question or the problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks the Problem was a formatting one. Sorry, I think I was sitting to long over it! May you know why there is also an error in line 9? It throws an UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 53: invalid start byte.

Comment: I've already tried it with 'ignore'.

Comment: Maybe your access to the zip file is wrong. You don't use the context manager ```z``` and access the zip directory directly instead of a single file. May take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open